# Unexpected newline occuring with use of for loops, ternary operators and conditions

Tags: c, output, newline

I understand that some functions automatically append newlines to their outputs, but I've encountered a scenario where a newline is not expected. I've tried to fix it and understand why it occurs in a multitude of ways, but to no avail. This is an output issue I haven't experienced before.

I am doing a very basic project from *C Programming: A Modern Approach* by K.N. King, Chapter 8, project 6: "B1FF filter", where certain characters get converted and printed as such. I used ternary operators combined with conditions to get the appropriate output. Here's the program:

```
/*  C Programming: A Modern Approach
        Chapter 8: Arrays, Project 5: B1FF filter
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    char message[50];
    int msg_len;

    printf("Enter message: ");
    fgets(message, 50, stdin);
    msg_len = strlen(message);

    printf("In B1FF-speak: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < msg_len; i++)
    {
        message[i] = toupper(message[i]);

        if (message[i] == 'A' || message[i] == 'B')
            printf("%c", (message[i] == 'A') ? '4' : '8');

        else if (message[i] == 'E' || message[i] == 'I')
            printf("%c", (message[i] == 'E') ? '3' : '1');

        else if (message[i] == 'O' || message[i] == 'S')
            printf("%c", (message[i] == 'O') ? '0' : '5');

        else
            printf("%c", message[i]);

        if (i == (msg_len - 1))
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                printf("!");

            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output isn't expected:

```
Enter message: C is rilly cool
In B1FF-speak: C 15 R1LLY C00L
!!!!!!!!!!
```

Why is there a newline between the modified string and the exclamation marks? I've clearly specified for the newline to occur after all text is printed, just before the loop terminates. I've tried alterations, such as printing a newline outside of the loop, not using a for loop for the exclamation marks etc., but it yields the same result. There doesn't seem to be an explicit reason for its occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

`fgets` includes the newline in what it copies to the destination `char` buffer. Hence your character-by-character printing routine passes it unaltered.

Result #1 for *fgets* on Google: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

> A newline character makes `fgets` stop reading, but it is considered a valid character by the function and included in the string copied to *str*.

Of course, as mentioned in the other answer, you can ignore this when printing, or null it out in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`fgets()` will save the newline character read to the buffer. If you don't want it, remove it.

Example:

```
fgets(message, 50, stdin);
/* remove newline character */
{
    char* lf = strchr(message, '\n');
    if (lf != NULL) *lf = '\0';
}
```

The meaning is:

```
fgets(message, 50, stdin); /* read one line from the standard input */
/* remove newline character */
{
    char* lf /* declare a variable */
        = strchr(message, '\n'); /* and initialize it with the pointer to the first '\n' in the string message */
    if (lf != NULL) /* check if '\n' is found */
        *lf = '\0'; /* if found, replace '\n' with '\0' and delete the newline character (and string after '\n', which won't usually present) */
}
```

Comment: @underscore_d Thank you for clearing that up, I must have missed the automatically appended newline in fgets()'s function reference.

Comment: So what exactly does that code block accomplish step-by-step? It did work perfectly by the way, so thank you for that. I just want to make sure I understand its functionality before using it.

Comment: @GabrielSaul I added some explanation.

Comment: Thank you, just looking at the strchr function now. So the use of the pointer allows the variable to manipulate the contents of the address when the target character is found?

Comment: @underscore_d Ahh, so could I write a condition that skips the newline character during the printing process?